# Multiple Connection Excepptions Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have built a scraper using Selenium 3.141.0 and python 3.6 that is using random proxies on each request. I have slowed the scraper down so its only doing one request at a time then pauses for 20 seconds before making the next request. When I am running the scraper the script gets terminated due to multiple exceptions.

I have tried handling the exceptions but that's not working as its happening multiple times in one session. I am not sure whats causing this and I tried tracing this but still not able to find the error. Any advise would be greatly appreciated. These are the errors I am getting and in this order.

```
    except TimeoutException as e:
        print("Time out exception" %e)
    except NewConnectionError as e:
        print("New connection error %s" %e)
    except MaxRetryError as e:
        print("Max Retry Error %s" %e)
```

ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: : Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=44499): Max retries exceeded with url

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue and for those of you who encounter this while using selenium within a class. You cannot use driver.quit() or driver.close() within the same method of your class. Instead you need to import unittest and inherit from unittest.TestCase. There is an example in the docs however, of you did not know about this then you are going to face some issues. In the class you want to create a setUp method and tearDown method and use these to build your program.

You do not have to use the unittest.main as in the below example you can use your own main and just write your code in their. I hope this helps.

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def test_search_in_python_org(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("http://www.python.org")
        self.assertIn("Python", driver.title)
        elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        elem.send_keys("pycon")
        elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source


    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()

def main():
    # place your code here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```